# Excel VBA Workdays

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have noticed that Excel VBA Workdays and Workdays_Intl output date in the serial number format. When I ran

```
Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Workdays_intl(StartDate,2),"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

I get date in the format mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy! However, when I change the format in the CODE to give the month name in 3 letters (mmm), I.e, dd/mm**m**/yyyy, now I get the date in the correct format.

I am sure what I'm doing wrong in the CODE, or what I can change to fix it, especially that when I type directly into the worksheet the date format is fine and my computer is set to use dd/mm/yyyy from control panel.

Any help on how to work around this will be much appreciated.

I am using Windows 10 / Office 2016

Comment: What are your regional settings set to in Windows?

Comment: I see you use "yyy". This is not supported formatting for custom date formats as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx Here it works appropriately with "dd/mm/yyyy" (so using 4x "y" instead of 3x)

Comment: @Rik, noted. It's a typho, yes on my CODE I've yyyy. Thanks

Comment: @pnuts yes I have. Still doesn't show

Comment: @DanDonoghue you mean like the date format? In control panel the short date is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, I had a similar issue to you years ago and it turned out to be regional settings, thought it may help but obviously not :(.